# Data type mismatch in SQL in MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

```
SELECT 
    [Employees].[EID], 
    [Employees].[CashierName], 
    [Employees].[Active] 
FROM 
    Employees 
WHERE  
    [Employees].[Active]='Yes';
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong in the above SQL statement. It continues to give me data type mismatch error

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what is wrong in the above SQL statement. It continues to give me data type mismatch error

Comment: Is Active a bit field? so you use 1 or 0 instead?

Comment: Where are you trying to run the query? In Access itself?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the *Active* field is a Boolean (Yes/No) field. In this case, it is best to write the condition like this:

```
[Employees].[Active]= TRUE
```